# Pull SQL data from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table called `db.data` and `db.info`. The `db.data` table has a `name` and `dateadded` column for every entry. The `info` table has a `name` and a `status` column for every name (status is either **y** or **n**). **I would like to pull the data from the db.data table for all the names added to that db by date but only if the status (the one in db.status) is n.**

I have been looking around and found `JOIN`, but that seems to only work if the data is the same in both tables. Here, the names are the same, but I want the data extracted from db.data but only in the status for the 'name' cell (which is in both tables) is set to 'n'.

Comment: Is there a common column between the two? For example, the db table could have an integer ID, and then the info table would use that ID to refer to the proper record in the db table. If not, you're going to have to rely on the name or some other commonality to relate the two tables.

Comment: Is there a foreign key relationship in place between the 2 tables?  Would you want to join on the name field or some other field?

Comment: Yes, both the tables have the column 'Name' in there. So db.data would have 10 entries sumbited by a name, e.g. Bob. db.info would have 1 entry for Bob with information about him, one of the pieces of info in the y or n status column. I need all the entries submited by bob from db.data but where the status filed is set to n in db.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select d.name, d.dateadded
  FROM db.info i, db.data d 
  WHERE i.name = d.name
    AND i.status = 'n';
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the data in each `name` column *is* the same for both tables. So a `JOIN` should work here:

```
SELECT db.data.*
FROM db.data
INNER JOIN db.info ON db.data.name = db.info.name
WHERE db.info.status = 'n'
```

Comment: I was typing the same query when the new replies bar popped up!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join on name between the two tables

```
SELECT d.name, d.date
FROM db.data d
    JOIN db.info i ON d.name = i.name
WHERE i.status = 'N'
ORDER BY d.date
```