# Pull From Two MySQL Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL tables with the following...

```
Apps
ID  |  Name
1      App1
2      App2
```

and...

```
Minutes
ID  |  AppID  |  Amount
1       1         10
2       1         15
3       2         35
```

I want to pull the Apps and display them by time used. Should look like this...

```
App2  35 minutes
App1  25 minutes
```

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pull SQL data from two tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368148/pull-sql-data-from-two-tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `JOIN` with a `GROUP BY`. To add the amounts together use the `SUM` aggregate funcion.

```
SELECT name, SUM(amount)
FROM `apps` 
JOIN minutes ON `apps`.`id` = `minutes`.`appid` 
GROUP BY `apps`.`id`
```

Comment: How would I go about displaying the total minutes?

Comment: Total minutes with no division between apps? Select sum(amount) from minutes

Answer (score 1):

Use a [JOIN (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29):

```
SELECT
    Apps.Name,
    Minutes.AppID,
    SUM(Minutes.Amount)
FROM Minutes
INNER JOIN Apps ON Apps.ID = Minutes.AppID
GROUP BY Apps.Name, Minutes.AppID
```